# Process Zip files in Hadoop map

Tags: hadoop

I am an newbie to Hadoop and Mapreduce.

Now I need to process a zip file in myproject using Mapreduce, like input have to be a zip file and the output may be zip or text file.

Can anyone give me sample or suggest me a link for that.

Thanks, 
varadhan.S

Comment: You can use SequenceFileInputFormat and SequenceFileOutputFormat. I don't know if it can work directly with zip files, or if you have to convert your file first, but generally this is how it works: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#closer

Comment: Just by googling .... https://gist.github.com/jteso/1868049

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently working on Hadoop and Mapreduce. there is no need to specially specify anything for Zip file. the hadoop automatically unzips and processes them. But, Output is Text what I am using. I am processing currently Huge number of Compressed files where each tar.gz file contains one text file each.

Regards
Balaram

Comment: HI Balaram, Thanks. I did as you said . But the output is not in the readable format. The output file contains unredable content not readable text content.